# Entity Framework and Load Testing

Tags: entity-framework, entity, load-testing

I am having a tough time to understand why this code is failing

I have a test method

```
IUnitOfWork unitofwork = EFUnitOfWork.CreateInstance();
IRepository<InformationRequest> informationRequestRepository = unitofwork.CreateRepository<InformationRequest>();
IEnumerable<InformationRequest> requests = informationRequestRepository.ToList();
unitofwork.Dispose();

EFUnityOfWork.CreateInstance calls the EFUnitOfwork Constructor
public EFUnitOfWork()
  {

     _currentContext = new MyDataContext();
  }
```

Here is the code for CreateRepository

```
public IRepository<T> CreateRepository<T>()
 {
     return new Repository<T>(_currentContext);
 }
```

The test above doesnt work on a load test. When i try to run it it says
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> **System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.**

I am disposing the context and creating a new one everytime. I dont understand where i am going wrong

Comment: We'll need to know whats inside EFUnitOfWork.CreateInstance() to be of any help.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: if you have created the instance with pertheadlifetime manager it wont work. With Unity2 you can inject the object you want ot use. It works for me. I am not sure if we cud do the same on the earlier version

Answer (score 2):

Your code `EFUnitOfWork.CreateInstance()` is a static method.

When 2 threads call this at the same time they could get back the same context. Then you could get the error that you see.

You could fix it by locking such that it is only called by one thread at a time. But time would introduce a performance bottleneck.